# How is it possible to send a valid variable to complete a string in python for printing emoji's?

Tags: python

Why doesn't this code work?

Code:

```
a="600"
print(f"\U0001f{a}")
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-6: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To overcome the syntax error:

The first backslash in your string is interpreted as a special character; since it's followed by a "U" (start of a unicode code point). To fix this you need to escape the backslashes in the string.

The direct way to do this is by doubling the backslashes:

```
print("\\U0001f"+ a)
```

You can also put `r` infront of the string

```
print(r"\U0001f"+ a)
```

Output:

```
\U0001f600
```

Finally checking if this displays an emoji.

```
>>> s = "\U0001f600"
>>> print(s)
```

Also to print emoji's, there are a few other methods.

Method1:

```
>>> print("\N{grinning face}")

>>> print("\N{slightly smiling face}")
```

Method2:

There is a package called `emoji` that can be utilized.

FURTHERMORE:

Let's consider a scenario, where we do string concatenation, and we expect emoji's to be printed like -

```
>>> res = "\\U0001f"+ a
>>> print(res)
\U0001f600
```

Here, the value printed is not a true unicode representation of a string. In these scenarios, I would recommend doing the following to keep things simple, when writing a script.

```
>>> a = "600"
>>> string = '1F' + a
>>> print(string)
1F600
>>> print(chr(int(string,16)))
```

Comment: why this code doesn't print emoji:
print(r"\U0001f"+ a)
or
print("\\U0001f"+ a)

Comment: I understand your problem, clearly. Adding an answer to my post :) Please confirm.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted, if you are all set. Thanks a lot!